# Two separate models - You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have an MVC application which has a content page, linked to a view model. It works well. But as soon as I add a view model to my content page (Generated within my layout), I get the error:

> You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.

I have created 'Sections' and try to bind to that section, as shown below.

// In my Layout page.

```
<div class='liveExample' id="sectionOne">   
    <p>First name: <input data-bind='value: firstName' /></p> 
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind='value: lastName' /></p> 
    <h2>Hello, <span data-bind='text: fullName'> </span>!</h2>  
</div>
```

// In my Index (content) page.

```
<div class='liveExample' id="sectionTwo">   
    <p>First name: <input data-bind='value: firstName' /></p> 
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind='value: lastName' /></p> 
    <h2>Hello, <span data-bind='text: fullName'> </span>!</h2>  
</div>
```

And the code:

// In my _Layout page:
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel1("Planet", "Earth"), $("#sectionOne")[0]); // This makes Knockout get to work

// In my Index page:
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel2("Planet", "Earth"), $("#sectionTwo")[0]); // This makes Knockout get to work

Here's a jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/4fe2f6mL/1/

I can't create a main view model, with the two models above as child views, as the ko.applyBindings is on separate cshtml files.

How can I get this to work, as I have a viewmodel for my Layout (Drives the menu, login, registration and "Welcome, Username" type stuff in the navbar)

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you are facing, but I've updated your jsfiddle without jquery and got the result working:
https://jsfiddle.net/Salmin/7tozbtj8/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you've linked works because the data-bound elements are *siblings*. When there's a *parent-child* structure, you cannot easily bind the *child* to a different viewmodel than the *parent*, using only `ko.applyBindings`.

Using partial .cshtml files and Razor to do templating sometimes clashes with knockout's own templating features... Personally, I tend to only define knockout [templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) in partials and use the `foreach` and `with` binding to get my views to render.

### Dirty fix

A quick and dirty fix for now, could be to create a custom binding that disables binds in a part of your DOM tree:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinds = {
  init: function() {
    return { controlsDescendantBindings: true }   
  }
}

ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.stopBinds = true;

// In your main js you bind the parent
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
ko.applyBindings({ test: "Parent value" }, parent);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
    <p data-bind="text: test"></p>

    <!-- start of your partial: -->

    <!-- ko stopBinds -->
      <div id="child" >
        <p data-bind="text: test"></p>
      </div>  
      <script>
        var child = document.getElementById("child");
        ko.applyBindings({ test: "Child value" }, child);
      </script>
    <!-- /ko -->
  
    <!-- end of your partial -->
</div>
```

### Slightly better fix

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.stopBinds = {
  init: function() {
    return { controlsDescendantBindings: true }   
  }
}

ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings.stopBinds = true;

// Expose the main vm
window.myVM = {
  test: "Parent value",
  childVM: ko.observable(null)
};

// Bind to document
$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(window.myVM);
  
  // Check if any callbacks have been registered and run them
  window.callbacks.forEach(function(cb) {
    cb();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
    <p data-bind="text: test"></p>

    <!-- start of your partial: -->
      <div id="child" data-bind="with: childVM">
        <p data-bind="text: test"></p>
      </div>  
      <script>
          // Register a callback
          window.callbacks = window.callbacks || [];
          window.callbacks.push(function() {
            window.myVM.childVM({ test: "Child value" });
          });
      </script>
    <!-- end of your partial -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. So would the layout section be a template, and the rest - normal? Or do you say that each view model belongs to a template? Throughout the application.